# Criar e destruir sessão

Tags: php

Bom dia !

Estou com uma dúvida sobre session. Por exemplo, eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde tenho 3 ambientes. O primeiro é o ambiente da loja virtual e os outros dois ambientes são escritórios virtuais tipo, dos Revendedores e dos Varejistas. Estes dois últimos são áreas restritas.
Então, preciso criar sessão para cada um desses ambientes, quando os diversos usuários acessarem? Ou seja, cada usuário precisa gerar uma sessão única a cada acesso, após eu destruir a mesma?
Por exemplo, estou enfrentando um problema no meu carrinho de compras.
A loja virtual contém um carrinho de compras. Ao fechar, preciso destruir a sessão, porém ao finalizar meu carrinho de compras e gerar a fatura.pdf, então destruo a sessão, porém não destrói.

Com relação ao carrinho de compras eu estou fazendo assim:

carrinho.php - onde crio a sessão

Destruindo a sessão carrinho após gerar a fatura.pdf:
Ainda dentro do arquivo carrinho.php
//destruindo a session carrinho...
include ("destroi_sessao_carrinho.php");

arquivo: destroi_sessao_carrinho.php

Preciso de uma luz. Onde estou errando.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: esse arquivo destroi_sessao_carrinho tem o que dentro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criando um nível de restrição na tabela dos usuários, por exemplo, você consegue o resultado.
Quando o usuário fizer o login, você busca esse nível de acesso e cria a sessão com ele:

```
$_SESSION['nivel_acesso']=$nivel_acesso;
```

Nas paginas onde ele não pode entrar você faz uma verificação:

```
if((!isset($_SESSION['nivel_acesso']))||($_SESSION['nivel_acesso']!=1)):// 1 seria o nivel necessario
    header('location: redirecionamento');//aqui você redirecionada para onde ele vai caso não tenha nivel de acesso
endif;
```

No arquivo `destroi_sessao_carrinho.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();//session_start() deve ser chamado antes de tudo
if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])):
    unset($_SESSION['carrinho']); 
    session_destroy(); 
    header("Location: produtos.php"); 
    exit();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Destruindo a sessão carrinho após gerar a fatura.pdf:
Ainda dentro do arquivo carrinho.php
//destruindo a session carrinho...
include ("destroi_sessao_carrinho.php");

arquivo: destroi_sessao_carrinho.php

<?php
//destruindo a session...
if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))session_start();

unset($_SESSION['carrinho']);

session_destroy();

header("Location: produtos.php"); 
exit;
?>

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado pelo aprendizado!

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar, sinaliza a resposta por favor. Gratidão.

Comment: O que devo sinalizar? Fechar este tópico?

Comment: Não, marcar a resposta como correta apenas

Comment: Em sinalizar, existem apenas 3 opções...

Comment: Sinalizar não, falei errado, marcar ela, como resposta correta